# Swift Animations - Perform a sequence

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm not entirely sure how to perform a sequence of animations.  If I try this it normally skips to the last one in the function.

Let's say I want to move 2 `UIImageView` (side-by-side) 300 points upwards,
then 2 `UILabel` (below the `UIImageView`) 300 points upwards as well.

Then, I want the Label to count up from 1 to 10 -for example-.

Finally, once the label has counted to 10,  I want the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to move back down by 300 points.

```
    func moveLabelUP() {

    label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x - 300, y: label.center.y)

    UILabel.animate(withDuration: 5) {

        self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.label.center.x + 300, y: self.label.center.y)

    func startLabelCountUp(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateLabel(){
    if self.current < elapsedTime {
        self.current += 1

        self.label.text = "\(self.current)"
    }else{
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

How can I connect these chain of events?

How can I apply a delay to when the timer starts for each `UILabel`?

I want the `UIImageView` to raise, the `UILabel` counts to 10, Then the `UIImageView` is lowered. This should repeated for the next `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to the right of the first ones.

Comment: Do you use constraints?

Comment: I'm not using constraints just now.
I am making a few different animations.  One set has to start off screen and appear.

The other is only moving upwards by 10points.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I have been using it. It is just a basic concept but you will get an idea. For my case I was using it with constants.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: { 

   // Your changes to the UI, eg. moving UIImageView up 300 points

   }) { (success) in

        // This executes when animation is completed
        // Create another animation here. It starts when previous ends

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration2, animations: { 

            // Your changes to the UI

            }, completion: { (success) in

                  // This executes when animation is completed

            })

})
```

Also check other frameworks that could help you, there are a few good ones. I tried [Cheetah](https://github.com/suguru/Cheetah) which supports chaining animations and works really well.

Just ask if you have any questions.